# Comparing unsigned char with signed char

Tags: c++

I have an array of `unsigned char` and an array of just `char`. I want to compare both of them so see if they're the same. Sometimes the comparison fails even when the bits are the same.

I know I can use `memcmp()`, but I'm just curious on how to do it manually.

```
char* arr1;
unsigned char* arr2;
...
if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) { //move zero extend vs move sign extend
        std::bitset<8> x(arr1[i]);
        std::bitset<8> y(arr2[i]);

        std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl; //The bits are the same.
}
```

Even though the char values might be the same, the comparison will say that they're different because arr1 gets moved into a register using a `movzx`(move zero extend) while arr2 gets moved into a register using a `movsx`(move sign extend).

This leads to problems with numbers such as 0x90 where the most significant bit is a one. Therefore a `movsx` so a 32-bit register will result in the value 0xFFFFFF90 while a `movzx` will result in the value 0x90 and the cmp instruction will say that they're different.

Comment: This is correct behavior. chars are promoted to ints in c++ and signed characters are sign extended.

Comment: Note that `char` can be signed or unsigned, depending on the implementation. Apparently yours uses signed. On an implementation that uses unsigned this issue would not arise. To frame the question more generically, instead of `char* arr1;` use `signed char* array;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, you just need to cast them both to a `(char)` when comparing.